LTSpice XVII - 2nd order Butterworth RC high pass filter FC=159Hz
LTSpice XVII.
I need a simple RC 2nd order Butterworth high pass filter, Fc=159Hz (Q=0.707) to use in single driver audio box to flatten the cone excursion under the maximun value of the driver for frequencies under 159Hz (I use the dedicated "Filters" option of WinISD, showing that the filter above is the suitable one).
In LTSpice XVII, I set up a RC filter diagram having the voltage surce set at 1V and a sweep from 10 to 20kHz, but simulating it, the Fc at -3dB was not 159Hz, rather about 426Hz, but at the cut off frequency of 159Hz, the gain is -9.55dB.
The two resitors value is 10k and the two capacitors value is 100nF, as per the textbook calculation for this filter type having the parameters I need.
I can't figure out what's going wrong.
Here's a screenshot of the circuit/simulation:


Here's the relevant circuit/simulation .asc file text:
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE -80 -48 -208 -48
WIRE 64 -48 -16 -48
WIRE 144 -48 64 -48
WIRE 320 -48 320 -96
WIRE 320 -48 208 -48
WIRE -208 0 -208 -48
WIRE 64 16 64 -48
WIRE 320 16 320 -48
WIRE -208 144 -208 80
WIRE 64 144 64 96
WIRE 64 144 -208 144
WIRE 320 144 320 96
WIRE 320 144 64 144
WIRE 64 192 64 144
FLAG 64 192 0
FLAG 320 -96 Out
SYMBOL res 80 112 R180
WINDOW 0 36 76 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res 336 112 R180
WINDOW 0 36 76 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap -16 -32 M270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 0.1µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=100 Irms=0 Rser=0.0371 Lser=1.1p mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="885382208006 WCAP-CSST 1206" type="X7R"
SYMBOL voltage -208 -16 R0
WINDOW 3 24 152 Left 2
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 1)
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMBOL cap 208 -32 M270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 0.1µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=100 Irms=0 Rser=0.0371 Lser=1.1p mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="885382208006 WCAP-CSST 1206" type="X7R"
TEXT -242 200 Left 2 !.ac dec 100 10 20k
TEXT -192 248 Left 2 ;Filtro RC del 2° ordine, Fc = 50Hz, Q = 0.2


Please draw a schematic including the load (speaker).

I don't see an "X" type in the schematic, so I'm assuming this is purely passive. Did you take into account the loading? Because if not then your computation of the -3 dB point is wrong. Please show an image of the schematic. This can be done as easily as just using the operating systems's snapshot capability and pasting it into the question.

@Daniele Can you also post a screenshot of the schematic?

@Mattman844, I understood what I need, a simple crossover circuit, it's plenty of on line too,  can use... Thanks a lot

@periblepsis I understood what I need, a simple crossover circuit, it's plenty of on line too, can use... Thanks a lot

If you remove the second resistor and capacitor you will find that the -3 dB point is where you expect it to be. The calculations work for a simple 1st order RC filter but when cascaded the second stage will load the first stage affecting the response.
First off, in the 2nd order filter you're no longer looking for the -3 dB point, you're looking for the -6 dB point.
Then you have to account for the loading. The second stage would need to be at least 10x the impedance of the first stage, and more would be better.
Here's a screenshot of a sim with both first and second order filters, the second stage is made 100x the impedance of the first.

You see that the frequency is the same, but 1st order is -3 dB and 2nd order is -6 dB. In your original circuit the loading makes it somewhere between those two values.
Of course you're also going to have to take into account the impedances of the source and load. If you try using something like this between a hifi amp and a speaker it's not going to work at all, for that you either need a filter with much larger caps and inductors, like you see in a speaker crossover, or the filter has to go before the amp.

Perfect, thank you very much.

I'll use a crossover circuit, using the high pass filter only (I'll decide if a 6dB, 12dB or 18dB per octave). There're many programs, on line too, I can use, specifying the speaker  impedance, besides the other parameters. Thanks a lot again!!!

Another tidbit of info here for future lookers. It’s impossible to get a 2nd order Butterworth using stacked 1st order RC filters. Each of those have real poles and to realize Butterworth polynomials you need to use imaginary pole pairs.

@DanieleColombi It sounds like you moved on to use a different solution. However, this answer in my opinion addresses your original question quite well. If you agree, then please consider “accepting” this answer by clicking on the gray checkmark next to the upvote/downvote buttons. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235
